# Ошибка: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-2.x

Python говорит:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Ругается на этот код.. Что не так?

```
self.printer.print('Loading fingerprints... ', 1, '')
```

Comment: @Namer, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

В  python версии 2.x оператор print является частью синтаксиса, и он думает, что вы его неправильно использовали.

Вы можете обойти это ограничение, переписав свой код следующим образом:

```
getattr(self.printer, 'print')('Loading fingerprints... ', 1, '')
```

Либо используйте python 3, там нет этой проблемы.

А еще лучше, если это ваш код, переименуйте метод.

Comment: `print` является **ключевым словом** в Питоне 2 (таким же как `if`/`else`/etc): `'print' in keyword.kwlist`. Кстати, выражение "`print` statement" можно перевести как "`print` операция" или "`print` инструкция" вместо "оператор `print`". Ещё можно использовать `from __future__ import print_function`, чтобы избежать `SyntaxError` и включить Питон 3 поведение.